# How this webpage data access works?

Tags: html, web, htmlunit, websecurity

I'm trying to get data from this site: [1] https://www.eurobet.it/it/scommesse/#!/calcio/?temporalFilter=TEMPORAL_FILTER_OGGI_DOMANI

I found this link where I can get the data in JSON format: [2] https://www.eurobet.it/detail-service/sport-schedule/services/discipline/calcio?prematch=1&live=0&temporalFilter=TEMPORAL_FILTER_OGGI_DOMANI

But there is a problem:
The JSON link Doesn't work every time in fact sometimes I get a 404 error.
I noticed that if I open the first link [1] before opening the second [2] it works perfectly.

This error is also more frequent when I try to scrape other data on the same site: [3] https://www.eurobet.it/detail-service/sport-schedule/services/discipline/calcio/piu-giocate/u-o-goal?prematch=1&live=0&temporalFilter=TEMPORAL_FILTER_OGGI_DOMANI

In this link [3] I try to get all "u-o-goal" odds but this link works only if (before starting my program to scrape data) in the main link [1] I press the "U/O GOAL" button -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nei5u.png

In my code, I'm using Java and htmlunit to scrape the data.

My question is: how this webpage works, why couldn't I open directly the links [2]/[3], I know that there is a sort of request and approval system behind but I can't see where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly open these URLs since the website (and many like it) will use cookies and bot-prevention techniques/session tracking so they can gather data about usage of their website. eg. they set a "Referer".

I'm not going to code a solution for you but I can at least help you understand what you need to do to get to where you want...

I've attempted to summarise how I'd typically unpick a request like this to recreate it, but in its essence, you need to understand the sequence of HTTP requests being made (this is how the web works - HTTP requests).

1. First you typically start with no session cookies and you access the site directly (no referer).
2. Once you access a website, typically the server responds with a session cookie for you to communicate back to the server a unique session ID so it has some sort of record of your browser having already been in contact.
3. Your browser may make more requests (asynchronously) and in doing so typically sends the cookies and the referring URL (usually the base Url will work... just don't use something that starts with something other than "https://www.eurobet.it"
4. anything else you're going to need to figure it out. Lots of headers are optional. Lots of query params have defaults.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64671815/7619034 - here's an answer I've given before that answers this type of question which comes up often enough.

so to explain a bit further, for your specific scenario...

When you access https://www.eurobet.it/it/scommesse/#!/calcio/?temporalFilter=TEMPORAL_FILTER_OGGI_DOMANI, the server responds with HTTP headers:

```
...
set-cookie: __cfduid=dd38d***********41125; ...
...
```

The rest doesn't look that relevant:

Going straight to the other request: https://www.eurobet.it/detail-service/sport-schedule/services/discipline/calcio?prematch=1&live=0&temporalFilter=TEMPORAL_FILTER_OGGI_DOMANI

This HTTP request takes (as input):

```
cookie: __cfduid=dd38d***********41125; mbox=session#6661556c.....b6e8cc1fa6f03#1608242987; at_check=true; s_ecid=MCMID%***********2021453010; AMCVS_45F10C3A53DAEC9F0A490D4D%40AdobeOrg=1; AMCV_45F10C3A53DAEC9F0A490D4D%40AdobeOrg=1075005958%7CMCIDTS%7C18614%7CMCMID%7C91883906030825914429183258312021453010%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CMCOPTOUT-1608248327s%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C4.4.1; s_cc=true
...
referer: https://www.eurobet.it/it/scommesse/
...
x-eb-accept-language: it_IT
x-eb-marketid: 5
x-eb-platformid: 1
```

Cookies are set in an initial request (typically) using `Set-Cookie` header and then are passed back to the server in subsequent requests using the `cookie` header.

I'm not certain how many of these values are relevant but you'd need to figure out where each came from in the chain of HTTP requests between the initial one and this one and you'd need to replicate them (see url above of my previous answer - warning this can be time consuming).

The other headers can be set statically most likely since they probably aren't due to change.

If you have access to curl on the command line, you can attempt to reconstruct some of these requests by hand. Some will be time sensitive since cookies do expire after an amount of time (see set-cookie header details for exactly when). Once you've reconstructed a working request, you can then start coding it in your application.

If you can work all this out you should be able to re-construct the chain of HTTP GET requests to get the JSON data you want. Good luck!

Comment: Wow... perfect answer.
I need to ask you a personal advice:
Is there a way i can try to reconstruct the http request directly in webpages (so that i can test saving some time and later implementing it to the code).

Comment: you can use curl to manually construct http requests. Or you could try using Selenium which might work without much work but is more heavy duty. If you want to do it in Java JSoup will work but you'll need to make each GET request individually. JSoup won't interpret the javascripts to make subsequent requests made when the browser runs the scripts. HtmlUnit (java lib) might work but you'd have to test it to find out